# Is it possible to "reset" cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there a command to reset Windows `cmd` window? I would like it to have the same effect as opening a new `cmd` window, but well, by reloading the current one.

What I want to do is install Python from the command line and then "reload" the window so I can use Python in a current window. I don't want to close the `cmd` and then open it again.

Comment: You know you can just type `cmd` from the prompt? It'll start a new session. Followed by `cls` and it will appear to be a new, fresh, window.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to install Python from the command line and then be able to start using it in the same `cmd` window.

Comment: What do you want to do? do you want to clear the content of the console window, or do you want to restore the initial environment?

Comment: @aschipfl neither I think. I edited the post to be more precise what my goal is.

Comment: What do you mean by "reload"? Why can't you use Python directly after installing?

Comment: @CodeCaster after installing python you have to restart `cmd`. I suppose it has sth to do with setting the path and environment variables (not sure).

Comment: @madasionka, Python's installer broadcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to top-level windows to inform programs that the registry keys that persistently store environment variables have been modified. When Explorer gets this message, it reloads its environment from the registry. CMD cannot get this message because there's no such thing as a "CMD window". It doesn't implement and own the console window. It just uses it, like any other console application. Thus it's simplest for the user to restart CMD from Explorer to inherit the updated environment, which means getting a new console.

Comment: The only other way to do it would be to explicitly add the necessary environment variables, e.g., by hand using `set` and/or `path`, or in a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this list](https://www.lifewire.com/list-of-command-prompt-commands-4092302). I think `cls` is what you are looking for:

> The cls command clears the screen of all previously entered commands and other text. The cls command is available in all versions of Windows, as well as in MS-DOS.

Comment: Please only post an answer once the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a brand new (reset) window with your current working directory set.

```
START "" "C:\Users\lit\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\cmd.exe.lnk" /K CD /D "%CD%" & EXIT
```

Comment: you may want to use `%comspec%` instead of your shortcut... And where we're at it, use `start` switch `/d`: `start /d "%cd%" "%comspec% /k" & exit`

Comment: @Stephan - I doubt if %ComSpec% will put the window in the same location and set colors the way the user's preferred shortcut does.

Comment: you have a point there. Consider to use `%appdata%` to avoid hardcoding your username.

Comment: @Stephan - Certainly, %APPDATA% could be used. But, that might or might not be the shortcut that the user wants to use.